# Sencha WebtestIt - browser launch url 'data:,'?

Tags: extjs, sencha-test

I have setup a simple test using Sencha Webtestit. When I run the test, it launches a browser but the url is always - 'data:,' which is not what I put in the test. No matter what I do, the result is the same. Any idea would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I found out what the problem was. It's the Forticlient blocking or filtering the URL. As soon as I stopped it, I can see the url I submitted.

Comment: For bypassing self-signed certificate, add 

 "acceptInsecureCerts": true

to the endpoint Capabilities. This will go straight to the test page. This works for Chrome. I am surprised this is not documented in WebTestIt.